# How Do I Access A Dynamically Created Control's Properties In C#

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am creating an instance of a button using a loop and finding it hard to modify the properties of a particular button instance.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
Button btn;
void CreateButtons()
{
   for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
   {
     btn = new Button;
     btn.Size = new Size(30,30);
     btn.Tag = i.ToString();
     flowlayoutPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
   }
}
```

Is there a was of accessing for example the first button itself rather than accessing its tag property. for example:

```
btn_Something.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

give a unique name to the buttons then cast the name of the button you'd want to have the properties changed into a button object then access and change its properties just as you'd do to a button added at design time.

here is the code

//insert ths in your loop
btn.Name = "button"+i.ToString();

//change the propery of buttoni (i can be any number in the range of your loop
btn =  flowLayoutPanel.Controls["button1"] as Button;

btn.ForeColor = Color.Blue;